# Thread doesn't start when app is running on Amazon windows server

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, signalr, windows-server

I manually start thread which runs SignalR on one page.
Currently my app is running on two different servers - Contabo and Amazon. Both are windows servers.

I logged the whole process in my database and found out that the thread doesn't start on Amazon server.

```
 public static void PushOrdersAsync()
    {
        int frequency = ParameterManager.GetInteger("OrderPushingFrequency");

        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (mPush)
            {
            
                Thread.Sleep(frequency * 1000);
                List<vOrder> orders = OrderManager.GetvOrders(OrderStatusEnum.Open);
                List<vOrder> completedOrders = OrderManager.GetCompletedOrdersAll();

                PushOpenOrders(orders);
                PushCompletedOrders(completedOrders);
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT : I am manually starting the thread when I start the website

Comment: I do not think it did not start the the method was called. Either it did error out with an exception or you have another async/await issue somewhere else producing due to a deadlock many pending tasks which prevent your task from running. A memory dump will tell what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

if your server is a datacentre edition you should check your license, make sure it does not have "activate windows" on the desktop

Comment: Windows is activated